# Jquery tool tip not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip, jquery-tooltip

I know there are tons of similar questions already in the SO on this same topic. I have been through them all.
It seems I can't get this to work. Please let me know where I am going wrong!
    This is how my code looks-

```
$("a").tooltip({
     bodyHandler: function() { 
        return "Tool Tip is working!"; 
     },
     showURL: false 
});
```

Here is a fiddle, The tool tip does not to work. Please help.

http://jsfiddle.net/LE7V3/175/

Comment: which is the tooltip plugin used

Comment: your code is just fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LE7V3/176/

Comment: Include tooltip plugin under External Resources tab as @ArunPJohny did.

Comment: Are you talking about JqueryUI tooltip? If yes, then please include css and jqueryUI JS file, then it should work.

Comment: I am using a old version of jQuery that was released back in 2011 and I cannot change that. I am using the jquery.tooltip.js which is what was release in 2011, before it was merged into the jQuery UI.

Comment: Never mind guys! I got it working... Thanks for the replies! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the fiddle you provided 
     http://jsfiddle.net/LE7V3/183/

```js
$( document ).tooltip();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<a href="#" title="tooltip">Display Tooltip</a>


<div  id= "tt-content" style="width:250px; display:none" >

<p>HTML TO BE DISPLAYED IN THE TOOLTIP.</p>
<p>EVEN MORE HTML</P>


</div>
```

here is the way tooltip works. you can use jquery on hover to set title of "a" tag instead of setting the tooltip itself . this will make the tooltip dynamic as u want .

hope this is helpfull

Answer (score 1):

The tooltip plugin is not available. You have not included it. if you debug `$("a").tooltip` you will see that its `undefined`.

@Arun P Johny has provided a jsFiddle with the solution in the comments.

Here's the link to his [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LE7V3/176/)